# How can I show these two metrics give the same topology?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

This question came up while showing the composition of a metric with a certain other 
function gives another metric. Suppose I have some metric space $(X,d)$ and a 
continuous, non-decreasing function $f$ on the nonnegative reals. Moreover, suppose 
that $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$, and $f$ also satisfies the triangle inequality in that $f
(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)$.

Using these properties, it is not difficult to show that $f\circ d$ is yet another 
metric on $X$, so $(X,f\circ d)$ is also a metric space.

I notice the (open) balls given by the metrics are of form 
$$
B_d(x,r)=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\lt r\}
$$ and 
$$
B_{f\circ d}(x,r)=\{y\in X\mid (f\circ d)(x,y)\lt r\},
$$ 
so it seems that the topologies generated by the base of open balls in each case 
would probably be the same. I would like to see how one would go about showing the topologies given by these two metrics are indeed the same. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: It suffices to show that in each open ball in one topology it's possible to find an open ball in the other topology. (The mental picture I have in my head is finding squares in circles, then finding circles in squares, which shows that $\ell^1, \ell^2, \ell^{\infty}$ metrics give the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ any two norm's are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @Qiaochu, I had heard those metrics gave the same topology, but didn't quite see why until now.

Comment: I was about to post an answer on your last question, so you deleted it in time. Don't feel bad about it, this happens to all of us (and the downvote was completely undeserved, IMO). Here's a more interesting question for you: Is an infinite set in the cofinite topology connected? [Challenge:](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/) is a countably infinite set with the cofinite topology path-connected?

Comment: Thanks @Theo, that makes me feel better. I just regret that I wasted a few of your minutes writing out an answer. But your first comment was more than helpful enough, for which I am grateful. I will look into these more interesting questions too.

Comment: No problem at all. I was doing some other things during a few minutes and my comment is just a summary of what I would have posted. The answers are given in the link above, but the connectedness issue should be something you should be able to work out on your own. Deciding about path connectedness is pretty hard (so I'm giving the answer about connectedness more or less away).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f: \mathbb R_+ \rightarrow \mathbb R_+$ a function as you've described. Given $r>0$ and $x \in X$ we want to find an $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$B_{f\circ d}(x,\varepsilon)\subset B_d(x,r)$. Set $\varepsilon=f(r)$ and take $w \in B_{f\circ d}(x,\varepsilon)$ then $f(d(x,w))<f(r)$ and since $f$ is non-decreasing it must be the case that $d(x,w)<r$ and therefore $w \in B_d(x,r)$.

To show that we can find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_d(x,\varepsilon) \subset B_{f\circ d}(x,r)$ is a bit trickier. Let $y \in (0,r)$ and pick $\varepsilon \in f^{-1}(y)$. Suppose $w \in B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ then $d(x,w)<\varepsilon$ and $f(d(x,w))\leq f(\epsilon)=y<r$ so $w \in B_{f\circ d}(x,r)$ as desired.

I think it's interesting to note that to get the balls to be contained in each other you don't really need <strike>the other two properties</strike> triangle inequality for $f$. But that it is needed in order to ensure $f\circ d$ is a metric.

Comment: You used the facts that $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous to ensure that $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: @Brian, thanks again.

Comment: Just so you know: "triangle inequality for $f$" is usually called "subadditivity of $f$" (after [Marcel Riesz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Riesz) who suggested that name to Hille). It is somewhat but not too closely related to convexity. There's quite an impressive body of literature on them.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, this explanation was very clear. Thanks also Brian and Theo for the useful comments.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you please explain why continuity implies that $f^{-1}(y) \neq \phi$?

Comment: @P-addict: We know that $f(0)=0$ and $f(r)=\epsilon$, so continuity of $f$ implies that $f\big[[0,r]\big]\supseteq[0,\epsilon]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks!

Comment: @P-addict: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Theorem from my book 
Topology, Sts. Cyril and Methodius University, Skopje, 2002 (in Macedonian) . 
The proof consists of five rows.

Theorem.   X is a set with two topologies **T1**  and **T2** , **B1**   is a basis for topology **T1**  and **B2**  is a basis for topology **T2** . If for every B1 in **B1** and every point x in B1 there exists B2 in **B2** , such that 
x is in B2 and B2 is a subset of B1,
then **T1** is a subset of **T2** .

Nikita Shekutkovski

Comment: For those of us who don't have the book, the proof would have been helpful. Regards