# Does the metric $d(x,y)=||x-y||^p$ for $0<p<1$ induce the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $0<p<1$ and $d: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$$d(x,y)=||x-y||^p, \quad x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n. $$

I have demostrated that $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does $d(x,y)$ induce the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @S.G. I don't think so (e.g. for $\alpha > 0$, $d_0(\alpha x)=|\alpha|^p d_0(x)$, so it violates positive homogeneity since $p\neq 1$.) Unfortunately, since it's not a norm, we can't use the fact that all norms in finite-dimensions induce equivalent topologies. Interesting question! My guess would be that the answer is no, but I don't have a counterexample at the moment.

Comment: This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60886/42969.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does generate the same topology. The reason? The balls are the same! If $B_1(x, r)$ is the open ball centred at $x$, radius $r$, in this metric space, while $B_2(x, r)$ is the corresponding open ball with respect to the usual Euclidean metric, then
$$B_2(x, r) = B_1(x, r^p),$$
as
$$\|x - y\| < r \iff \|x - y\|^p < r^p \iff d(x, y) < r^p.$$

Comment: Beautiful explanation, but there is a minor typo: one of the two balls in the equality should have $1$ as an index!

Comment: @Didier Ah yes, thank you!

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you!